# Make a div to be over multiple div

Tags: html, position, center

Here's the site link with the "backbone" structure: http://www.vomow.net

Basically what i need to to is to put a div centered on the page, the same height, but 800 px width. The div needs to be with no background.
I've tried with "z-index" but didn't have any luck.

Can someone help?

Comment: See who sent you first the answer that helped you - then set it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on your website this :

```
element.style {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

and it helps.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be useful, but I think you should use:

```
position: absolute;
```

To center div with absolute position use:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -400px;  //this is because your div's width is 800px
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to center a div, you could do like this:

`#myDiv {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}`

But I'm not sure whether you want this div to cover some of the ones you have at the top. In that case, you could use `position: relative;` and then adjust the `top` property.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be written as follows:

```
#yourdiv{
margin: 0px auto;
width:800px;
}
```

Good luck!